# Windows Server 2022 persistent route with RRAS connecting user (SSTP VPN)

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, persistent

I have Windows Server 2022 at one end and Keenetic router at the other.
They connected with SSTP VPN.
Windows as server and Keenetic as client (road warrior using mobile connecction).
There are some users behind Keenetic with 192.168.87.0/24 network.
When it's connected to Windows RRAS VPN server it gets address 11.11.11.3, where 11.11.11.1 - Windows server.
After this I add route:
route -P add 192.168.87.0 mask 255.255.255.0 11.11.11.3
and it starts working.

```
Persistent routes:
  Network address        Mask             Gateway      Metrics
     192.168.87.0    255.255.255.0       11.11.11.3       1
```

But it works right till the moment the user reconnects..
I see connection in RRAS MMC console, I see the route in routing table, but it doesn't work.
I need to delete route and add it again.
And it start working again.

Are there some options somewhere to up the route when client connects?
Tried to debug logs and catch the event to start script with Event Manager, but RRAS doesn't log to events incoming connections, I can see only outcoming connections from Windows VPN.

Tried in PS:

```
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 192.168.87.0/24 -InterfaceAlias "RAS (Dial In) Interface" -NextHop 11.11.11.3
```

It adds right route but doesn't work either.

Can someone help with that? Some ideas?

update: Made a workaround script till the moment I find proper way adding route.

```
    while($true)
{
$hostname = "192.168.87.1"
$isReachable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostname -Quiet
if ($isReachable) {
    Write-Host "$hostname is reachable."
    Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" >> E:\tmp\route87.log;
    echo "OK, working." >> E:\tmp\route87.log;
} else {
    Write-Host "$hostname is not reachable."
    Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" >> E:\tmp\route87.log;
    echo "Restart route" >> E:\tmp\route87.log;
    route delete 192.168.87.0 mask 255.255.255.0
    route add 192.168.87.0 mask 255.255.255.0 11.11.11.3
}
Start-Sleep 60
}
```